# How to change element text of only one element with python elementtree

Tags: python, elementtree

I have the following xml example file:

```
<Book>
    <Location>page10</Location>
    <Chapter>
        <Location>page11</Location>
    </Chapter>
</Book>
```

I want to change the text value of element `<Location>` right beneath `<book>`.
Using findall gives both 'Location' elements.
Using find gives the first, that could be right, but in case element 'Chapter' is placed before Location than I get the wrong element.

Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use paths..

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> frag = '<Book><Chapter><Location>page11</Location></Chapter><Location>page10</Location></Book>'
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(frag)
>>> tree.findall('./Location')[0].text
'page10'
>>> tree.findall('./Location')[1].text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```